# An application for credit monitoring

Tags: web-apps, finance

I am looking for an credit monitoring application that can tell me regularly the changes on my credit. Here is what I am looking for:

- Could be paid
- Must be web-based
- Must monitor the three main credit bureaus (Equifax, TransUnion, Experian)
- Must be able to see my credit report on demand
- Should alert me when suspicious activity is shown on my credit.

I am using the Credit Karma service, and although it is a great and free service, two of my biggest complaints are that it only shows what it is reported from TransUnion, and I need to wait for a week in order to refresh the credit information.

I need the tool to be web based, as I have many computers and want to access this from all of them without installing something on all of them.

Comment: Why this is not a question about a software recommendation? A website is a piece of software. I am asking about a recommendation for a need that I have. Please expand why this question is off-topic.

Comment: After reading this question: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/191/can-i-ask-for-recommended-websites, I think that I understand the problem with my question. I hope that the changes that I made will make the question on-topic.

Comment: Yes, that's the reason: we deal with software, i.e. ways to perform tasks on a computer, rather than with data sources. Sorry for not making the specific closure reason clear.

Comment: I made some changes to the wording of the question. It is still off-topic?

Comment: The boundary is fluid, but essentially you're still looking for a data source, no matter how you word the question. I personally don't feel strongly either way about this question, other community members may decide to reopen it or not.

Comment: I feel that this is a Webapp (based on the criteria: 
**Given you had the program of that thing yourself and would run it on your own server without any data from the original source, the program would still be useful.** ) You want a tool that queries these three services and display the results handily. Could you explain why you need it web based?

Comment: I need it web-based because I want to access the tool from any of my computers, without the need to be installing the tool in each computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would check out [Mint Credit Monitor](https://credit.mint.com/) which is a familiy of the multi-award winner [Mint,](https://mint.com/) the budget manager, by INUIT INC.. It has most of the characteristics you are looking for:

- They monitor the 3 biggest credit bureau Equifax, TransUnion, Experian
- You can see your credit report whenever you are
- The have identity thief protection (note: I haven't tested this personally nor I have someone to ask, since nobody has been victim)
- Identity thief evaluation, which they monitor how much information about you is available and where
- They don't offer suspicious spending themself but as part of the main product called Mint.
- Credit score evaluation
- Both services (Mint and Mint Credit Monitor) are not so integrated as they could made you think
- Has a 14 day free trial.

Some of this features I haven't tested them myself due obvious reasons, as I haven't been in the need of them.